# 502 bad gateway for favicon.ico

Tags: html, docker, flask, amazon-ecs, http-status-code-502

I deployed a Flask app to AWS ECS instance but when the app is run, it shows "502 Bad Gateway". When I check the console, it says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)" for favicon.ico. But the thing is I haven't added favicon in my html file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTRPN.png)
What might be the issue here?

I was trying to deploy an ML model. I dockeried the app and deployed it as an AWS ECS service. Thats when this issue occured.

Comment: for starters, you always should have a favicon...

Comment: Browsers always make a request for the favicon, if you don't have one just ignore that error message. If your app isn't actually loading in the browser, then there is another error happening besides the favicon thing.